# Update linked tables when moving directories

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 3 Access databases linked and when I move them from one computer to another I have to update them...

I have been trying with the code below, which seems to work fine up to the refresh part... when I get the "could not find installable ISAM"... any ideas how to solve this?

```
Private Sub RelinkTables()
Dim oldConnection As String
Dim newConnection As String

Dim currentPath As String
currentPath = CurrentProject.Path

Dim tblDef As TableDef

For Each tblDef In CurrentDb.TableDefs
oldConnection = tblDef.Connect
If Right(oldConnection, 7) = "l.accdb" Then
    newConnection = currentPath & "\PL.accdb"
Else
    If Right(oldConnection, 7) = "d.accdb" Then
        newConnection = currentPath & "\MasterDB - consolidated.accdb"
    Else
        newConnection = currentPath & "\analysis.accdb"
End If
End If

tblDef.Connect = newConnection
tblDef.RefreshLink

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: MS says its because ACcess is unable to access the information in the <pathname> check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `.Connect` property for a linked table whose source is in another Access database.

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblUser").Connect
;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\loginexample.mdb
```

Your code does not include the *";DATABASE="* piece when you build those *newConnection* strings.  You can add it to your *currentPath* string, and then it will be included in your *newConnection* strings.

```vb
currentPath = ";DATABASE=" & CurrentProject.Path
```